# number of roots of polynomial of order n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

from  theorem  of algebra,it is well know that polynomial of order  n  has  exactly n roots,for exmaple quadratic equation like   $ax^2+bx+c$   has  three  cases
let  $D=b^2-4ac$   ,so   we have

1.$D>0$
we have two real solution  $x_1,x_2$

2.$D=0$
we have again two  solution ,but   algebraic multiplicy  of two  ,or $x_1=x_2$

3.$D<0$

we have   complex solution  two roots,but  because we know that  if  $a+bi$  is solution  of polynomial,then it's conjugate  $a-bi$   is also,so can we conclude that  for complex cases  we  have  at least  $n+1$  roots?because if  we have two complex,then  conjugates of  both is also solution,so in this  case $n+2$ solution we  would have?thanks

Comment: No. You only have at most two different roots: $\,a+bi\;,\;a-bi\,$

Comment: but for cubic equation,we have one complex and two real yes?but  we also have  conjugate  of  complex solution,i mean when we have odd power

Comment: @dato For real cubic function, you have either $3$ real roots, or $1$ real + $2$ complex roots.

Comment: ok thanks,i  was thought  that 2 real +1 complex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the two complex roots are conjugate of each other, so you dont have to worry about any extra complex roots.

As pointed out by Yimin, when the coefficients $a,b,c$ are not in $\mathbb{R}$, the complex roots do not have to be conjugate of each other.

Comment: provided the coefficient of the polynomial are real.

Comment: @Yimin: A polynomial of degree $n$, with $n\ge 1$, and coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ has, counting multiplicities, exactly $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, this is the fundamental theorem. I simply said, conjugation argument is based on some assumption. I just comment on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If an '$nth$' degree polynomial is supposed to have a complex root, then there automatically exists a complex conjugate to it. This implies that there are $2$ complex roots and the remaining $(n-2)$ roots can be anything.

You are confused with the fact that if a complex root exists then its conjugate should also exist and this will be the $(n+1)th$ root. But the fact is that complex conjugate is already a root of the '$n$' possible solutions.

**NOTE: Note that the complex roots are always in pairs and hence you will always find even number of complex roots.**

Hope the answer is clear !